# Solve trigonometric equation for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the following equation:
$$y(\cos\theta) - x(\sin\theta) = sin(10* \big( y\big(\sin\theta\big)+(x(\cos\theta\big)))$$
I know that:

$sin(a+b) = sin(a) cos(b) + cos(a) sin(b)$, but i do not know how to solve?

Comment: There should not be an algebraic solution for $y$. Since $y$ is also containt in the argument of $\sin$ on the RHS. That means it should not be possible to isolate $y$.

Comment: The right-hand side is given by $$\sin(10y\sin(\theta)+10x\cos(\theta))$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes it is

Comment: If so, then you will need a numerical method.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner any example or tutorial please

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can you provide a separate answer for it?

Comment: you must write down values for the parameters,

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner is this mean that i can not get a general solution for it ?

Comment: Yes that's what i mean.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner this mean that it can not be applied in a pc programm

Comment: You will need values for $y,\theta$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner you mean values for x and theta? not y and theta , am i right?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner because is unknown

Comment: $y$ is also unknown?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner so if theta =45 degree and x range from -100 up to 100, would you please provide the answer?

Comment: And what is the unknown variable?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i want y to be in the left hand side i.e. isolate y, it will be used in a c++ program so it is better to be isolated

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner and actually my problem in y isolation

Comment: You can not Isolate $y$ in your equation and $x$ also, i can give you only numerical values, as i said above.

Comment: ok, i wander how it will if x was 120 and theta = 45

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch that sort of gets the answer.  Let $z = y\sin\theta +x \cos \theta.$  Then your equation is $z'= \sin 10 z.$  This differential equation is solvable, but ugly.

But now you have $ y\sin\theta +x \cos \theta = \mbox{ugly}(\theta),$  which you can solve for $y$.

Comment: how we can solve for y? what i know that ugly(θ) is function of y, so how we can solve it??

Comment: i mean that ugly(θ) is also unknown so how we can solve ?